# EF Many to many relationship where key is known in Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to navigate from one entity in my model to another. But I can't seem to get it right:

Here are my entities:

```
public class Import
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class PersonParameter
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int ImportId { get;set; }
    ...
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Import Import { get; set; }

}

public class ImportDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int ImportId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Import Import { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonParameter PersonParameters { get; set; }

}
```

For every import, a person has a set of PersonParameters and also several ImportDetails that needs to know about the PersonParameters.

Now EF thinks this is a one to many relationship and adds ImportDetail_Id to the table when the database is generated. It is not. I'd like EF to use the keys allready in place.

Basically I'd like EF to create this SQL for me:

```
select * from importDetails d
left join PersonParameter pp on d.importId = pp.importid and d.PersonId = pp.PersonId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map also to configure n-m relationship.
I did not understand your model but your n-m configuration should be similar to this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany<Car>(user => user.OwnedCars)
    .WithMany(car => car.Owners)
    .Map(mapping =>
    {
        mapping.MapLeftKey("OwnerId");
        mapping.MapRightKey("CarId");
        mapping.ToTable("Owner_Car");
    });
```